# Tkinter grid system not working

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code, which should work, but for some reason actionFrame and infoFrame are put underneath each other...

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("TNT Manager")

root.configure(background='grey')
root.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

plannerFrame = Frame(root, bg='grey')
plannerFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NSEW')

plannerFrame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=15)
plannerFrame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
plannerFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=5)
plannerFrame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=2)

actionFrame = Frame(plannerFrame, width=500, height=400)
actionFrame.grid_propagate(0)
actionFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NSEW", padx=1,pady=1)

infoFrameWid(actionFrame) #for now just adds text widget inside frame

infoFrame = Frame(plannerFrame, width=200, height=400)
infoFrame.grid_propagate(0)
infoFrame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="NSEW", padx=1, pady=1)

infoFrameWid(infoFrame)

saveFrame = Frame(plannerFrame)
infoFrame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)
```

The problem I have is the infoFrame widget is going above the actionframe widget. They are on the same row. If you take away the saveframe widget it works fine.

[image]

Comment: I've added it at the bottom, sorry for forgetting!

Comment: Done that but don't have enough reputation to post images

Comment: F1 = row 0, column 0.
F2 = row 0, column 1.
F3 = row 1, column 0 & 1.

Comment: [pic link](http://imgur.com/0ZqoUi9)

Comment: hey you did silly mistake check at last you have given infoFrame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=1, pady=1) it should be saveFrame .grid(row=1, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)

Comment: i think my answer solved the question isnt it?

Comment: Yep, but I can't upvote, no reputation :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to change  atlast

```
saveFrame = Frame(plannerFrame)
infoFrame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)
```

to

```
    saveFrame = Frame(plannerFrame,width=700, height=400)
    saveFrame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)
```